# Subgroups of finite reflection groups that do not fix a point

Tags: finite-groups, coxeter-groups

Let $(W,S)$ be a finite irreducible Coxeter-System of rank $n$ and $E$ be a real reflection representation of $W$. Let $x\in E$ and suppose that the isotropy group of $x$ is generated by one element in $S$. Now which are the subgroups of rank $n-1$ that do not stabilize $x$?

Comment: When you say "do not stabilize" do you mean that the stabilizer of $x$ in the subgroup is trivial?

Comment: yes, that is what I mean

Comment: If $s_1$ to $s_n$ are the roots and $s_1$ is the root which fixes $x$ then the group generated by $s_2$ to $s_n$ would be what I need. However, is this all that can happen?

Comment: Tom: There are other possibilities too. Consider do instance what happens in rank 2 cases.

Comment: No I am a bit confused specially by the "answer" of Ben.

Comment: What do you mean by the "rank" of a subgroup?  For example, what is the rank of the alternating group inside the symmetric group?  Are you considering only certain special subgroups, like parabolic subgroups?  A parabolic subgroup has a well-defined rank, but other subgroups?  (My apologies if there is some general definition of rank that I don't know.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consider the Coxeter Graph: The subgroups you are looking for are those that you get by removing one edge...

Comment: This is incorrect and does not even attempt to answer the question.

Comment: why? isnt that all clear from the Coxeter Graph?!

Comment: Ben: you also have to think about conjugated of standard parabolics. If you think your "solution" is correct, try to write the details.